# Directive inside another directive in angularjs while the inner directive is from another module

Tags: angularjs, module, directive

I have directive declared as:

```
     var myApplication = angular.module("myApplication", ["myOtherApplication"]);

    myApplication.directive("dir", function () {
        return {
                 restrict: "E",
                 transclude: true,
                 template: "<div> Text  </div>",
      }; 
    });
```

and I have another directive written in another module

```
    var myOtherApplication= angular.module("myOtherApplication", []);

    myOtherApplication.directive("myDirective", function () {
       return {
          restrict: "E",    
          template: "<div > More content </div>",
       };
    });
```

The html below is not rendering the inner directive:

```
    <div ng-app="myApplication">
        Some content ...
        <dir >
             Some more content ...
             <my-directive></my-directive>

      </dir>
```

is not rendering anything.Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [ngTranslude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngTransclude) directive if you want to preserve inner content of the directive and make Angular compile inner staff:

```
myApplication.directive("dir", function () {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        transclude: true,
        template: 
          "<div>" + 
            "Text " + 
            "<div ng-transclude><!-- insert content here --></div>" +
          "</div>",
    }; 
});
```